# selenium по-моему что-то перепутал

Tags: python, парсер, request

в общем, есть у меня функция, которая проверяет данные пользователя на достоверность, то есть пользователь вводит логин и пароль, а функция проверяет реальны ли они. Тестил на своем компьютере ос- win10, хочу закинуть на vps сервер, ос - ununtu 20.04, ошибка, `selenium.common.exceptions. InvalidArgumentExcept: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable`, на stack overflow прочитал что можно добавить параметр `executable_path='путь до geckodriver'`, но при вводе данного параметра выходит новая ошибка `TypeError: WebDriver () got an unexpected keyword argument ‘executable_path'`, selenium точно новой версии, вот вам функция если нужно:

```
def try_to_sign_in_upload_kaspi(User_login, User_password):
    
    ff = '/snap/bin/geckodriver'
    
    option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()

    option.add_argument("--headless")

    with closing(webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=ff, options=option)) as browser:
         # функционал, который не выводит ошибок
```

Comment: @Эникейщик , это же шутка... Я понимаю, что это моя ошибка в коде либо ошибка при установке драйверов, а за документацию спасибо, я ее долго искал и не нашел, не знаю почему

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [Эникейщик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/282277/%D0%AD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA), благодаря документации, которой вы отправили я нашел решение вопроса. В новой версии, чтобы указать путь к драйверу нужно использовать не executable_path в параметрах webdriver.Firefox(), нужно:

1. Заимпортить сервисы, `from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service`
2. Создать сервис и уже в нем указывать executable_path, `service=FirefoxService(executable_path='путь к geckodriver')`
3. Указать сервис как параметр webdriver.Firefox(), `webdriver.Firefox(service = service, options=option)`

У меня проблема решилась, если же у вас, у тех кто столкнулся с этой проблемой, продолжает возникать ошибка то попробуйте:

1. Обновить selenium
2. Переустановить или установить браузер, я использовал firefox, но можно другой любой, посмотрите реализацию в документации [документация](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/upgrade_to_selenium_4/#executable_path-has-been-deprecated-please-pass-in-a-service-object)
3. Попробуйте переустановить geckodriver